# Margin-top not working when an image is centered horizontally - Phonegap

Tags: html, css

I am new to webdesign, I am using Phonegap (HTML5) I centered my image horizontally this way:

**.html**

```
  <div id="loginholder" >

    <img id="image_person" src="img/icon_login.png" />
   ...
```

**.css**

```
    #image_person {
        display:block;    
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
     ...

    #loginholder{
        background-color: #29AAE1;
        height: 200px;
        width: 70%;  
        margin: 0 auto;
   }
   ...
```

- Please why my margin-top is not working?

Comment: Maybe because in the parent div of `loginholder` you have margin-top and margin-bottom set to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger layout. Add overflow:hidden to #loginholder

Answer (score 1):

I'd add `padding-top: 30px;` to `#loginholder` instead and remove the `margin-top: 30px;` from `#image_person`:

**CSS**

```
#image_person {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#loginholder {
    background-color: #29AAE1;
    height: 200px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bazC4/.

Also, if you wanted the `#loginholder` the same size, just remove `30px` from the `height` so it would be `height: 170px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a div:

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/MBLKs/

CSS:

```
   #loginholder {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#stabilizer {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Images behave like characters, so entering them doesn't always work. In this case, the position of the wrapping div and the image offset each other, leaving the image in the middle. Now your margin-top and everything else should work.

Answer (score 0):

The margin might be collapsing with the parent, causing the 30px margin to appear above the loginHolder div ([more on margin collapsing](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing&ei=zFyHU-OOJ4qmyAT5roKIDQ&usg=AFQjCNGXDLYVjoCWThOhA0qcugOEaPVqlw&bvm=bv.68114441,d.aWw)). To resolve this, you could do one of the following:

1. Add a `border` or `padding` to loginHolder; this separates the margins so they won't collapse.
2. Change to using `padding-top` on the image instead of `margin-top`.